# FastAPI CORS troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, cors, fastapi

I'm having some troubles with FastAPI and CORS. Can you give me a working example of it?

FastAPI router:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.post("/post")
async def postHandler(request: Request):
    data = await request.json()
    return {"resp": "Created a new game!"}
```

JavaScript:

```
async function apiRequest (url, method, reqBody) {
    const reqParams = {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
        }
    };
    if (method === "POST") reqParams["body"] = JSON.stringify(reqBody);
    const response = await fetch(url, reqParams);
    const data = await response.json();
        return data.resp;
}
```

Comment: why are you adding **response** headers into your **request**? That's likely to trigger a CORS pre-flight - does your code handle a CORS pre-flight? `I'm having some troubles` please state the nature of the "troubles" in as much detail as you think would help troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Can you share some more details about the errors?
Is there anything in the network tab of your application on the web app?
Does the request actually make it to the server? Can you share any logs if so

Comment: [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/) correctly states: *`allow_credentials` - Indicate that cookies should be supported for cross-origin requests. Defaults to False. Also, `allow_origins` **cannot be set to `['*']` for credentials to be allowed, origins must be specified.***